# Skip JSON.map() for the subsequent elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngoninit-vqalyq)
(Please check the browser console for output)

I have a JSON customerItemResponse in a format

```
{
    "totalResults": someNumber,
    "results": [
        {
            "totalItem": 406,
            "customerId": "10000"
        },
        {
            "totalItem": 468,
            "customerId": "10001"
        },
        {
            "totalItem": 20,
            "customerId": "10002"
        },
...
```

Then I have another JSON customerInfo:

```
{
    "totalResults": someNumber,
    "results": [
        {
            "customerId": "10000",
            "region": "4",
            "area": "42",
        },
        {
            "customerId": "10001",
            "region": "4",
            "area": "43",
        },
        {
            "customerId": "10002",
            "region": "5",
            "area": "52",
        },
```

Now I have to create a JSON in a format

```
[
    {
        region:'4'
        regionDetails:[
                          {
                              area:'42'
                              customerDetails:[
                                              {
                                                   customerId:'10000'
                                                   totalItem:406 
                                              },
                                              {
                                                   customerId:'10005'
                                                   totalItem:301 
                                              },
                                              ]
                          },
                          {
                              area:'11'
                              customerDetails:[
                                              {
                                                   customerId:'10010'
                                                   totalItem:11 
                                              },
                                              {
                                                   customerId:'10021'
                                                   totalItem:105 
                                              },
                                              ]
                          },
                      ]
    },
    {
        region:'5'
        regionDetails:[
                          {
                              area:'52'
                              customerDetails:[
                                              {
                                                   customerId:'10002'
                                                   totalItem:52 
                                              },
                                              {
                                                   customerId:'10027'
                                                   totalItem:310 
                                              },
                                              ]
                          },
                          {
                              area:'41'
                              customerDetails:[
                                              {
                                                   customerId:'10017'
                                                   totalItem:109 
                                              },
                                              {
                                                   customerId:'10041'
                                                   totalItem:450 
                                              },
                                              ]
                          },
                      ]
    }

]
```

This is the logic I have written:

```
customerData=<CustomerDataInterface[]>[]

mapJson() {
        this.customerItemResponse.map((res, index) => {
            this.customerInfo.find((obj) => {
                if (obj.customerId == res.customerId) {
                    this.customerData.length
                        ? this.customerData.map((data, index1) => {
                              if (data.region == obj.region) {
                                  data.regionDetails.length
                                      ? data.regionDetails.map((regDetails, index2) => {
                                            if (regDetails.area == obj.area) {
                                                regDetails.dealerDetails.push({
                                                    customerId: obj.customerId,
                                                    totalItem: res.totalItem,
                                                });
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            if (index2 == data.regionDetails.length - 1) {
                                                data.regionDetails.push({ area: obj.area, dealerDetails: [] });
                                            }
                                        })
                                      : data.regionDetails.push({ area: obj.area, dealerDetails: [] });
                                  return;
                              }
                              if (index1 == this.customerData.length - 1) {
                                  this.customerData.push({ region: obj.region, regionDetails: [] });
                              }
                          })
                        : this.customerData.push({ region: obj.region, regionDetails: [] });
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(this.customerData);
    }
```

Now the output of the console has several `region` repeated. And suppose if I have `6` unique `region` but the `this.customerData.length` is `31`.

I think `return;` is not working as expected. And is not skipping the subsequent element.

Comment: Are area numbers unique? Like can `region` 1 and 2 both have `area: '11'`?

Comment: `Area` is unique. If `region` 1 has an `area` 11, no other `region` will have it.

Comment: As an FYI, the purpose of `.map` is to transform/return data. As it is, it looks like you are treating it as `.forEach` and this could be confusing to someone else reading your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an efficient way to resolving the issue using js Maps. We can build maps with info about corresponding region and then areas. and after the data is built into maps - convert it back to simple js structures, such as object and arrays

```
mapJson() {
    const customerToTotalMap = new Map(this.customerItemResponse.map(({customerId, totalItem}) => [customerId, totalItem]));
    const regionsMap = new Map();
    for(let {customerId, region, area} of this.customerInfo) {
      let regionAreas;
      if(regionsMap.has(region)) {
        regionAreas = regionsMap.get(region);
      } else {
        regionAreas = new Map();
        regionsMap.set(region, regionAreas);
      }
      
      let areaInfo;
      if(regionAreas.has(area)) {
        areaInfo = regionAreas.get(area);
      } else {
        areaInfo = [];
        regionAreas.set(area, areaInfo);
      }
      areaInfo.push({customerId, totalItem: customerToTotalMap.get(customerId)});
    }
    this.customerData = [...regionsMap.entries()].map(([region, areas]) => ({
      region,
      regionDetails: [...areas.entries()].map(([area, customerDetails]) => ({
        area,
        customerDetails
      }))
    }))
    console.log(this.customerData);
}
```

Comment: But why iterate an array twice when you can do it by iterating just once?

Comment: @Naman where are they iterating the array twice?

Comment: `customerToTotalMap` already iterated them once.

Comment: @Naman this solution is O(n + m) where n is length of `customerItemResponse` and m is length of `customerInfo`, while your solution is O(n * m * n) i gues which is much more complex

Comment: That is for mapping `customerId -> totalItem`. The second loop is for `customerInfo` array to create region and area specific mappings

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also your code is a lot cleaner than mine. Thank you

Comment: One more help. How can I sort `customerDetails` based on `totalItems` for each area?

Comment: just do `customerDetails: customerDetails.sort((a,b) => a.totalItems - b.totalItems)` in the last piece of code where we combine everything to simple js object

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to @Andrei's answer. It creates an object literal as mapper. Also, it uses mapping between the region and area when they are created. So, finally you can just get the values of the regionMapper object without going through the mapper objects again

```js
const customerItemResponse=[{customerId:10000,totalItem:77},{customerId:10001,totalItem:37},{customerId:10002,totalItem:295},{customerId:10003,totalItem:458},{customerId:10004,totalItem:248},{customerId:10005,totalItem:35},{customerId:10006,totalItem:280},{customerId:10007,totalItem:147},{customerId:10008,totalItem:439},{customerId:10009,totalItem:401},{customerId:10010,totalItem:489},{customerId:10011,totalItem:414},{customerId:10012,totalItem:287},{customerId:10013,totalItem:391},{customerId:10014,totalItem:125},{customerId:10015,totalItem:207},{customerId:10016,totalItem:197},{customerId:10017,totalItem:151},{customerId:10018,totalItem:225},{customerId:10019,totalItem:333},{customerId:10020,totalItem:361},{customerId:10021,totalItem:225},{customerId:10022,totalItem:242},{customerId:10023,totalItem:150},{customerId:10024,totalItem:52},{customerId:10025,totalItem:475},{customerId:10026,totalItem:494},{customerId:10027,totalItem:30},{customerId:10028,totalItem:189},{customerId:10029,totalItem:112},{customerId:10030,totalItem:482},{customerId:10031,totalItem:283},{customerId:10032,totalItem:159},{customerId:10033,totalItem:440},{customerId:10034,totalItem:461},{customerId:10035,totalItem:76},{customerId:10036,totalItem:84},{customerId:10037,totalItem:392},{customerId:10038,totalItem:296},{customerId:10039,totalItem:293},{customerId:10040,totalItem:135},{customerId:10041,totalItem:348},{customerId:10042,totalItem:338},{customerId:10043,totalItem:444},{customerId:10044,totalItem:15},{customerId:10045,totalItem:32},{customerId:10046,totalItem:67},{customerId:10047,totalItem:277},{customerId:10048,totalItem:65},{customerId:10049,totalItem:95},{customerId:10050,totalItem:290}],
  customerInfo=[{customerId:10000,region:"3",area:"32"},{customerId:10001,region:"2",area:"22"},{customerId:10002,region:"2",area:"25"},{customerId:10003,region:"3",area:"31"},{customerId:10004,region:"2",area:"25"},{customerId:10005,region:"1",area:"11"},{customerId:10006,region:"1",area:"14"},{customerId:10007,region:"5",area:"55"},{customerId:10008,region:"5",area:"51"},{customerId:10009,region:"4",area:"45"},{customerId:10010,region:"1",area:"14"},{customerId:10011,region:"1",area:"12"},{customerId:10012,region:"3",area:"33"},{customerId:10013,region:"2",area:"25"},{customerId:10014,region:"4",area:"41"},{customerId:10015,region:"3",area:"32"},{customerId:10016,region:"5",area:"55"},{customerId:10017,region:"2",area:"23"},{customerId:10018,region:"3",area:"33"},{customerId:10019,region:"5",area:"51"},{customerId:10020,region:"4",area:"42"},{customerId:10021,region:"1",area:"12"},{customerId:10022,region:"1",area:"14"},{customerId:10023,region:"1",area:"14"},{customerId:10024,region:"1",area:"13"},{customerId:10025,region:"4",area:"45"},{customerId:10026,region:"3",area:"34"},{customerId:10027,region:"2",area:"24"},{customerId:10028,region:"4",area:"45"},{customerId:10029,region:"2",area:"22"},{customerId:10030,region:"2",area:"22"},{customerId:10031,region:"2",area:"21"},{customerId:10032,region:"3",area:"33"},{customerId:10033,region:"1",area:"11"},{customerId:10034,region:"3",area:"33"},{customerId:10035,region:"3",area:"32"},{customerId:10036,region:"2",area:"22"},{customerId:10037,region:"4",area:"41"},{customerId:10038,region:"3",area:"31"},{customerId:10039,region:"5",area:"51"},{customerId:10040,region:"2",area:"23"},{customerId:10041,region:"4",area:"45"},{customerId:10042,region:"1",area:"14"},{customerId:10043,region:"5",area:"54"},{customerId:10044,region:"3",area:"34"},{customerId:10045,region:"5",area:"51"},{customerId:10046,region:"4",area:"42"},{customerId:10047,region:"5",area:"53"},{customerId:10048,region:"1",area:"11"},{customerId:10049,region:"3",area:"35"},{customerId:10050,region:"5",area:"51"}];
  
const customerItemMapper = {}

for (const c of customerItemResponse)
  customerItemMapper[c.customerId] = c.totalItem

const regionMapper = {},
      areaMapper = {};

for (const { customerId, region, area } of customerInfo) {
  let regionKey = `Region_${region}`,
      areaKey = `Area_${area}`,
      totalItem = customerItemMapper[customerId];

  if (!(regionKey in regionMapper))
    regionMapper[regionKey] = { region, regionDetails: [] }

  if (!(areaKey in areaMapper)) {
    const o = { area, customerDetails: [] }
    areaMapper[areaKey] = o;
    regionMapper[regionKey].regionDetails.push(o) // area-region relation
  }

  areaMapper[areaKey].customerDetails.push({ customerId, totalItem })
}

console.log(Object.values(regionMapper))
```

Comment: One more thing. How can I sort `areaMapper` value based on `totalItem`?

Comment: agree, the result is the same. The only thing is: I believe js objects performance isn't very good on long datasets.

Comment: @Naman you could sort the `customerItemResponse` array before processing it  `customerItemResponse.sort((a,b) => a.totalItem - b.totalItem)`